# What methods are available to manage (delete/reinstall/update) drivers on a non-booting window 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, system-restore

I have got the PC of a friend with a Windows 10 installation which does not boot. Here are the circumstances:

1. Windows version should be 10.0.19044 (21H2) which I got from `ProgramData\Microsoft\Diagnosis\osver.txt` other methods like loading the the Software Hive and looking at the CurrentVersion key of the registry didn't show any usefull information in regards to the windows version. Also using `winver` or `systeminfo` in the cmd prompt of the recovery environment didn't result in anything useful.
2. It gets into the recovery environment but nothing else.
3. No form of Safe Mode boots
4. The System Restore has two recovery points, both of which are unable to finish the restore process.
5. The only hard disk currently hooked up is a 250gb SSD. There are 3 Partitions on it, 100mb system reserved, ~500mb some hidden recovery partition and the rest is the actual partition for the windows installation.
6. Diskpart only showed the additional information for the hidden partition, the other two are displayed as regular partitions (so no boot partition was detected)
7. `chkdsk /f /r /x` showed no problems and ran successfully
8. Boot method is MBR (the disk is not shown to have GPT active)
9. allready ran the different `bootrect` commands. `/fixboot` returns with
   'access denied'
10. `SYSTEM32/Logfiles/Srt/SrtTrail.txt` only contains this notable line
    "Name: Check for pending package install Result: Completed
    successfully. Error code = 0x4". Because of this I already tried to remove pending package installations via `DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions` (yes I am 100% certain I used the corret drive letter) but the command returned with `can't perform operation`
11. Restoring a registry backup is not possible, as the `System32\config\RegBack` folder is empty (thanks to some win 10 update in 2018)

The friend told me, the last time he could use the PC some error message box poped up and he only remember that it was something mentioning AMD.

The PC itself has

- CPU: Intel Core i5-4590
- Graphics Card: Sapphire(AMD) Radeon R9 270X
- Motherboard: MSI    H97M-E35 (MS-7846) with an Chipset of intel h97

So after already spending quite some time on this, my suspicion is that some graphics driver update went wrong.

The question now is: How do I reset/uninstall/update/reinstall a driver for a windows installation which is not booting and I only really have access via the command prompt of the windows recovery environment?
(the driver I would like to replace in this case would be specifically the graphics driver)

Comment: See if the Graphics card manufacturer offers a driver update on bootable USB (separate from your OS).

Comment: What happens when you boot, when does it get stuck? I'm not sure that a driver became bad all of a sudden - try a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @John a quick search tells me no. But I will try and email them to see if the have something like this.

Comment: System does not boot so Windows is not working, so Repair Install will not run.

Comment: @harrymc it gets into the windows loading screen (black scree, blue logo, circle rotating) and then it gets a BSOD with the message "critical process died". Subsequent boot attempts lead to this page about changes to the startup. and after that it gets into the windows recovery environment.
I haven't tried a repair install yet. those are sort of the last option, but are on my list.

Comment: Sorry, Repair Install was the wrong link for your case - you need to simply install Windows. If the installation locates the existing Windows instance, then it will just upgrade it, the same as any major Windows update.

Comment: @harrymc any idea how I can figure out what version and kind (Home, Pro etc.) is already installed? 
or is it irrelevant? also I think the win10 version was aquired by updating from a win 7 version.

Comment: If you can boot into the command line, use this : `reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\windows nt\currentversion" /v ProductName`

Comment: danks I will try that out.

Comment: So I tried to reinstall it over the old windows installation. The upgrade option told me it can't proceed so I only had the option for the "custom installation". All the installer then did was put the all files into a "Windows.old" folder and install windows normally from there. There was no inplace upgrade or anything possible. 
Now I made a complete clean install as my last solution.
Thanks for the help thou :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would:

- before anything, **Backup** (I'd use something like Acronis, Aomei backupper or clonezilla) so you have a point to go back to, in case something goes wrong.

I am not sure I'm convinced that the snag is the driver, but rather a botched windows update, however assuming you're right:

try:

- check the bios battery of the mother-board 
  there is a slim chance that the bios battery could have lead to motherboard settings being changed or not held correctly. *(chance is slim, but I've seen it)*
- Try to see if the machine will boot into safe-mode
- See if you can download the original graphics card driver for this machine and system drivers wouldn't hurt either.
- boot into a recovery environment (I really like [kyhi's Rescue Disk](https://win10.guru/toolkit-item-kyhis-rescue-disk/) 
  There is a tool there called **EasyBCD** (that can really help determine if your BCD is pointing to the correct partition or even set it to boot to safe-mode)
- then download **[Driver explorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer/)** to a usb stick and run it from within the live environment.

*This is a really nice tool for adding or deleting drivers from an offline system*

### Alternatively

There is a chance that your issue might be related to the partition table and BCD environment.

- Try deleting the other partitions that are NOT:

```
 The tiny boot partition,
 The Windows Partition
 The recovery partition
```

- Then re-format the little boot partition and running a rebuild of the bcd again.

```
 bootrec /fixmbr
 bootrec /fixboot
 bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

There is a more Manual approach to all of this, but running this from the Kyhi Windows PE environment makes your life a lot easier.

### Another to try (once you have a backup)

Convert the system over to UEFI from a live environment:

1. Clear all partitions

```
  diskpart
    sel dis 0  # Make sure the disk 0 is the one you want to clear
    clean 
    convert gpt
    create part efi size=500 offset=5
    format quick fs=fat32 label=System 
    ass letter=m
    create part msr size=128
```

2. Restore the Windows partition to the free space of the drive
3. Run from a command line, still within the live environment: 
   Find out the drive letters for your EFI partition and windows partition,
   if necessary assing a drive letter to each 
   *assuming your EFI disk that we created on step one is still **M:** and the windows partiton go letter* **N:**

```
  bcdboot N:\windows /s M: /f UEFI
```

4. Switch the motherboard to boot from UEFI and test from the temporary boot menu.

Comment: So I tried to repair via easyBDC but not from Kyhs bootable but instead from hirens. Since the method to build a current version of Kyhs did not include the easyBDC. At least as far as I have seen it. I Also tried the Driver explorer which couldn't load the drive store from the non-booting windows installation. 
It seems as if the registry was majorly corrupt. Also attempts from me to read out like the installed windows version and the used product key failed too because the registry hive couldn't be loaded/read. 
Thansk for the suggestions but it became a clean reinstall in the end.

Comment: I know you've already reinstalled, but if it is just a registry issue, the registry files can be found in c:\windows\system32\config.
There are 5 files that you can basically mount into \HKEY_USERS on regedit on the live environment. Go to file /load Hive and name them anything temporary as you load them:
c:\windows\system32\config\
- SOFTWARE.
- SYSTEM.
- DEFAULT
- SAM
and for the user= c:\users\YourUser\ntuser.dat...

then test and see if they load, then go to:  File / Unload Hive for reach one.